# Which one of them require multiple processors?Multitasking,Multiprocessing and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

1.Is it possible to acheive multithreading with single processor?

Comment: Yes; in fact many modern CPUs are multicore ones

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes i know.... but I am asking with single core

Answer (score 1):

**Multiprocessing :** Several jobs can run at the same time.(So, it requires more than one processor)

**Multitasking :** Sharing of processor among various tasks, here some scheduling algorithms come in to context switch tasks (Not necessarily need multiple processor)

**Multithreading :** A single process broken into sub tasks(threads) which enables you to execute like multitasking or multiprocessing and their results can be combined at the end. (Not necessarily multiple processors)

Links:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking#Multithreading
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprogramming#Multiprogramming

Edit : To answer your question , multithreading is quite possible with one processor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

With a single processor, the threads will take turns executing. Exactly how this is implemented is up to the operating system.
If the work done is computation heavy, you will probably lose more than you gain because of the added scheduling overhead.On the other hand, if there is a lot of waiting, for example for network resources, you can gain a lot from using several threads on a single processor.

Comment: will it improve performace if we have multicore processor?

Comment: yes, provided you have as many threads as cpus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

The threads can get their turn in time-slice i.e. each thread can be executed for some particular interval and then other will get turn.

For more info.

[Time-slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeslicing)
[Preemption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 0):

Threads concept mainly used for acheiving the multitask in a single processor,to minimize the ideal time of the of the processor we are using the multithreading concept in java.